# $.post not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and it doesn't work in IE8. Even though I see the form data on the client. Nothing makes to the server. Has anybody seen this ?

```
var data2 = $j('#form2').serialize()
alert(data2)
$j.post(urlBase + 'tabulae/userInvitation/ajaxValidateInviteeDomain', data2, function(data) {
  if (data[0] == true) {
    e.target.form.action = e.target.value;
    e.target.form.submit();
  } else {
    $j('#dialog-invalidEmail').dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        OK: function() {
          $j(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}, 'json')
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: How is this code invoked ? Are you sure the form is not submitting before it runs $.post.

Comment: No I don't see any errors in the console.The same code works in Safari and FF and Chrome

Comment: The code is invoked on the submission of a form.

Comment: Did you clear the cache and try ? IE has that problem

Comment: ok, do you do a `preventDefault()` ? So that the form is not submitted before the `$.post` is executed ?

Comment: Are you saying that the `$.post()` doesn't work, or that the form submit within the success handler doesn't work?

Comment: Well I don't see any data going to the server side method in IE 8. For other browsers it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Add semicolons to these lines and see if it works:

```
var data2 = $j('#form2').serialize();
alert(data2);                       ^
            ^
```

Comment: You shouldn't need semicolons in this case anyway (JS only requires them for some cases).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the proxy and the Webgateway. There was no data going between the client and the server and hence the issue. Thanks for all the answers